# ggplot generic without fortify

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

I have a data structure that I want to provide easy ggplot-ability for.

Usually you simply convert it into a `data.frame` by providing a `fortify` generic method, but in this case that would be huge, since my data is four-dimensional (n×n×v×v). A good fit for ggplot’s `x` and `y` aesthetics would be the 2nd and 3rd dimensions of that matrix, let’s call them, `v1` and `v2`.

If `v1` and `v2` are known, a n×n matrix of points remains that can efficiently be converted into a 3×n×n matrix of coordinates and values, i.e. the final `x`, `y` and `colour` aesthetics.

So what I’d like to achieve is to call

```
mm <- MyClass(...)
ggplot(mm, aes(x = 'foo', y = 'bar'))
```

And ggplot internally doing (using the aes information)

```
xyc <- make.tidy(mm@data[, , 'foo', 'bar'])
```

Comment: Are you sure fortify effectively computes the four-dim matrix? As I understand, it only computes lazyly what is required, i.e. plotted.

Comment: ggplot works as follows: it accepts any object, and calls `data <- fortify(data)` on the whole object. later it uses `data` after the `fortify` call to do `plyr::eval.quoted(aesthetics, data, plot$plot_env)`, which evaluates the expressions in `aesthetics` in `data` (which is treated as environment)